# How to get the whole image datas (like: pieces*3*224*224) via torchvision.datasets and transforms?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, torchvision

ImageFolder can package the images, It's easy to get one RGB data:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize([256, 256]),
         transforms.RandomCrop(224),
         transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
         transforms.ToTensor()])
    src_folder = datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(root_path, src_dir), transform=transform)

src_folder[0][0]  # we can get the first picture's RGB data matrix:3*224*224
```

However it is too difficult for me to get the whole RGB data in one time!

This is my trial:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize([256, 256]),
         transforms.RandomCrop(224),
         transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
         transforms.ToTensor()])
    src_folder = datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(root_path, src_dir), transform=transform)

    # Get the RGB data corresponding to each picture
    src_num = len(src_folder)  # suppose 100
    src_data = src_folder[0][0].unsqueeze(0)  # 1*3*224*224
    for num in range(1, src_num):
        # Concatenate each picture's data matrix, ideal results: 100*3*224*224
        src_data = torch.cat((src_data, src_folder[num][0].unsqueeze(0)), 0)
```

However this methods need **amounts of time** to run with it, it's unexpected.
Is there any easier methods to obtain the whole data matrix(like 100*3*224*224)?